# C header/API for intel dal?

Tags: intel-oneapi, intel-dal

I'm trying to use Intel Onedal (https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/components/onedal.html) to do some machine leaning training/inference.
Based on the source code I found in github, it seems that all the code is in C++. However it seems that this project is supposed to provide C header/binding, that I'm interested in.

So, do these header exist somewhere? I couldn't find them.
At the same time, there exist a python wrapper for this lib, so I think it must use the C binding to access the native lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native part of oneDAL is C++ library, there is no C API. All C++ APIs/implementations are located in [/cpp](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneDAL/tree/master/cpp) directory. Currently there are two types of supported C++ APIs:

- CPU only API, which is called `daal` by historical reasons;
- New API called `oneapi`, which as part of [oneAPI open specification](https://www.oneapi.com/) and can run on various hardware including CPU, GPU, ...

At the moment daal4py is based on CPU only API, header files [can be found here](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneDAL/tree/master/cpp/daal/include).

All Python bindings are based on Cython and part of [daal4py repository](https://github.com/IntelPython/daal4py).